# Data passing from a separate asynctask to a fragment

Tags: android

I have a separate asynctask class which creates a url for me. I tried to use an interface in the onPostExecute to send the url to my fragment, but could not managed it. I was always doing the same process in the fragments by forcing to implement the interface in onAttach.

After myTask.execute(), i simply wait for the result with a progress dialog on the screen. Everything works fine until the interface's callback method is called.(nullpointerexception)

How can I force the fragment to make it implement the interface? (I need to send the data directly to the fragment, not via activity)

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found my mistake finally. As ePeace mentioned in his answer. In my Asyntask class, I created a constructor which throws nullpointerexception is the listener is null.

```
AsyncListener listener;
public ReportFactory(AsyncListener a)
{
    if(a == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Listener cant be null");
    }

    this.setListener(a);
}

public interface AsyncListener {
    public void onComplete(String url);
}


public void setListener(AsyncListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

After that, in the fragment class, I created a listener. (Have a global reference in the class to the listener, so that you can use it on the other places in the fragment lifecycle)

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

  listener = new AsyncListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String url)
    {
        URL = url;          
        webview.loadUrl(URL);         
    }
};      
}
```

And finally, in the onCreate method I created my Asyntask and gave the listener as a paramater.

```
ReportFactory factory = new ReportFactory(listener);
factory.execute(usr, designFile);
```

Hope it works for you who might need it later. Thank you very much for your time ePeace.

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a interface and have a method or a constructor in your asynctask that accepts said listener.

Create the listener in your fragment and set it for you asynctask.

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
AsyncListener listener;
Object result;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    this.result = result;
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(listener != null)
        listener.onComplete(result);
}

public void setListener(AsyncListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public Object getResult() {
    return result;
}

public interface AsyncListener {
    public void onComplete(Object object);
}
}

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncListener {
private Example task;

public static ExampleFragment newInstance(Example task) {
    this.task = task;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Object object;
    if((object = task.getResult()) == null)
        task.setListener(listener);
    else
        onComplete(object);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

public void onComplete(Object object) {

}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the asynctask class, I could not connect it to the fragment. How would you use "setListener" in your sample in the fragment?

Comment: Depends on when the asynctask is create. I'll edit my post for some options.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I get some errors. Task.setListener does not accept listener as a parameter. That is also what my problem is. Code works perfectly, except when it needs to call the  onComplete, i got a nullpoiter error.

Comment: I have shared the part of my solution, thank you very much for your time and effort.